# Как воспроизвести багу в Android

Tags: java, android

Бывает так что появляется баг, который нереально и не понятно как воспроизвести.

А это нужно чтобы удостовериться что после исправления данного бага других багов не возникнет. Как быть? Может есть способ. Инструменты, программы для такого рода деятельности в Android?

Comment: Написание тестов не спасает?

Comment: @Komdosh, не умею

Comment: Тогда это ответ, вам нужно научиться писать unit и инструментальные тесты.

Comment: @Komdosh, Можете дать ссылку на хороший туториал для новичка. Который null в тестах

Comment: Если честно у меня нет каких-то сохранённых ссылок. Данная ссылка кажется неплохой https://stfalcon.com/ru/blog/post/simple-unit-tests-for-android